# Cómo visualizar el CKEDITOR5 utilizado en Django en Angular

Tags: javascript, python, angular, django

estoy utilizando **Django** para la parte del backend y **Angular** para la parte del frontend.
Al utilizar Django como backend implementé el **CKEDITOR5** para poder editar contenido, pero tuve un pequeño percance, y es que al querer visualizar ese contenido con Angular me muestra el código **HTML** (*a lo crudo*), estuve buscando por varios sitios sobre la **pipe safe** para ver si me ayudaba a solucionarlo, pero no me quedó bien en claro, me pueden ayudar a solucionar este problema por favor, espero haya sido claro. Gracias.

Comment: Al querer visualizar el contenido del ckeditor, debes indicar que no requiere escapes HTML antes de la salida en el template, de la siguiente manera: `{{ description|safe }}`.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, cómo le puedo indicar de que no quiero escapes? yo tengo esto, tal cual me has dicho {{work1.description|safe}} de igual forma me tira error y tengo una pipe sacada de https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/angular-safe-pipe-implementation-to-bypass-domsanitizer-stripping-out-content-c1bf0f1cc36b

Comment: gracias de igual forma, pude encontrar la solución con este link detallando lo que me has dicho más o menos: https://medium.com/@AAlakkad/angular-2-display-html-without-sanitizing-filtering-17499024b079